# Excel - Filter data that exists in 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to Filter an excel column with data that exists both in Column A and Column B
For example Lets say that I have Column A with the following rows:
(A, B, C, D, E)
And Column B with:
(C,D,Z)

I would like to filter Column A that will show only:
(C,D)

This is because those are the 2 only rows with values that exists in both Columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a helper column, something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,$B:B,1,0)),0,1)
```

And filter by it: 0 - no match, 1 - match.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$13,0)),"",A2)
```

It outputs the duplicate data in a separate column.

Find more details from the source of this solution: [extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/774-excel-find-duplicates-in-two-columns.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, so probably irrelevant now.

Another option would be to have conditional formatting on column A based on formula above and set format that could be used for filter e.g. interior color or font color